# Tesseract: High CPU Usage and slow speed, only when running multiple processes in parallel

Tags: ocr, tesseract

## Problem

`pytesseract.image_to_string()` takes too much time when I run the script through supervisordd, but executes almost instantaneously when run directly in  shell (on the same server and simultaneously with supervisor scripts).
Apart from taking too much time, the processes are also showing high CPU usage.

Time taken by `pytesseract.image_to_string()` when run via Supervisord: ~30s
Time taken by `pytesseract.image_to_string()` when run via Bash: 0.1s

This problem only occurs, if there are a lot of processes, executing `pytesseract.image_to_string()`, being run via supervisord (around 22 instances). If I reduce the number of instances (to around 10), the scripts executed via supervisord also run smoothly.

#### System Information

OS: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS (bionic)
Supervisord: Version 3.3.1
Tesseract: Version 4.0.0-beta.1
Python: Version 3.6
PyTesseract: Version 0.2.5

ulimit -a

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 127357
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 16384
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 8096
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 127357
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Let me know if you need any more information.

### Edit 1 (or I know what's NOT the source of this problem)

I am fairly certain that it is not an issue with Supervisord.

When I run one instance from an ssh shell, the function (`pytesseract.image_to_string()`) is executed smoothly (i.e takes only 0.1s), while there are 10 instances being run via Supervisord.
When I start another instance from a new ssh shell, both the instances (ones started from ssh) run smoothly most of the time.
When I start yet another instance from a new ssh shell, all the three instances start choking, taking around 10s to execute the function. This time keeps on increasing as I add more instances via shell.

So the problem can be replicated even with a shell.

#### More Information

I ran the program with `strace -T -f` but I could not figure out what exactly is causing the spike in time.

For a function call that takes 1s

```
Top 10 system calls sorted by time taken
1.504530    [pid 29921] <... wait4 resumed> [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 30166
0.503915    [pid 29932] <... select resumed> )      = 0 (Timeout)
0.503472    [pid 29932] <... select resumed> )      = 0 (Timeout)
0.500524    [pid 29933] <... select resumed> )      = 0 (Timeout)
0.500515    [pid 29933] <... select resumed> )      = 0 (Timeout)
0.500514    [pid 29932] <... select resumed> )      = 0 (Timeout)
0.500512    [pid 29933] <... select resumed> )      = 0 (Timeout)
0.069869    [pid 30169] <... futex resumed> )       = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set)
0.035989    [pid 30167] <... futex resumed> )       = 0
0.016002    [pid 30168] <... futex resumed> )       = 0
```

For a function call that takes 9s

```
Top 10 system calls sorted by time taken
9.795787    [pid 29921] <... wait4 resumed> [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 30106
0.515960    [pid 29933] <... select resumed> )      = 0 (Timeout)
0.511955    [pid 29933] <... select resumed> )      = 0 (Timeout)
0.507979    [pid 29932] <... select resumed> )      = 0 (Timeout)
0.507968    [pid 29932] <... select resumed> )      = 0 (Timeout)
0.505257    [pid 29932] <... select resumed> )      = 0 (Timeout)
0.503988    [pid 29932] <... select resumed> )      = 0 (Timeout)
0.503978    [pid 29932] <... select resumed> )      = 0 (Timeout)
0.503975    [pid 29932] <... select resumed> )      = 0 (Timeout)
0.503974    [pid 29932] <... select resumed> )      = 0 (Timeout)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Disabling multiprocessing in tesseract fixed the issue. It can be done by setting `OMP_THREAD_LIMIT=1` in the environment.

See https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/898#issuecomment-315202167

Comment: it works!
OMP_THREAD_LIMIT is an environment variable and must be prepended before tesseract command

Answer (score 2):

In python process:

```
import os
os.environ['OMP_THREAD_LIMIT'] = '1'
```

It fixes threading overhead.